# Select specific element of list of lists

Tags: python, list, select

I have a list of lists:

```
[[0.01, 0.19, 0.72], [0.03, 0.27, 0.31], [0.23, 0.74, 0.09]]
```

I want to extract a different element from each list. So from the first list the second element, but from the second and third list a different element. I saved those in a different list;

```
selections = [1, 2, 0]
```

So the output I would like to have is:

> 0.19, 0.31, 0.23

Comment: `[sublist[select] for sublist, select in zip(my_list, selections)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l=[[0.01, 0.19, 0.72], [0.03, 0.27, 0.31], [0.23, 0.74, 0.09]]
selections = [1, 2, 0]
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i][selections[i]])

Output:
0.19
0.31
0.23
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
my_list=[[0.01, 0.19, 0.72], [0.03, 0.27, 0.31], [0.23, 0.74, 0.09]]
select=[1,2,0]
j=0
selector=[]
for i in select:
    selector.append(my_list[j][i])
    j=j+1
selector
```

output

```
[0.19, 0.31, 0.23]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [[0.01, 0.19, 0.72], [0.03, 0.27, 0.31], [0.23, 0.74, 0.09]]
selections = [1, 2, 0]

for i,j in zip(x,selections):
    print(i[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

**I use Python Matrix**

```
list=[[0.01,0.19,0.72],[0.03,0.27,0.31],[0.23,0.74,0.09]]
nums=list[0][1],list[1][2],list[-1][0]
print(nums)
```

*Output*

```
(0.19, 0.31, 0.23)
```